# Force.com IDE for OSX - Where to configure VM settings?

Tags: force.com, ide, java

We have one developer that upgraded to mountain lion and it installed jdk 1.7, we installed 1.6, and configured the softlinks, but when force.com ide starts up it has vm set to the Frameworks folder within the old vm, but the jdk doesnt have this folder. Anyway, in windows there is the eclipse.ini or forceide.ini file where I can configure this. My install has neither, I searched my hard drive and dont see either file. I tried manually creating both in the same folder as my app but neither seem to get read... Any ideas?

Comment: Start looking at using MavensMate - https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate-SublimeText

Comment: Agreed, on a MavenSMate for sublime text is the way to go

Comment: agreed Mavesmate is cool, but some folks prefer eclipse, it is what they are used to, so I have to figure this out :)

Answer (score 2):

The eclipse.ini file is inside the eclipse application bundle. right click on the main Eclipse app and pick "show package contents" then navigate into the Contents -> MacOS folder to find the eclipse.ini file.

Comment: thanks I found it, what is the flag for the vm, is it --vm or -vm and where does it need to go, I have found conflicting stuff in google.

Comment: I tried doing what this says http://wiki.eclipse.org/%C2%A0eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Mac_OS_X_Example using --vm and it doesnt seem to help

Comment: also, both the eclipse.ini and the forceide.ini are there, with similar stuff in them, which is used? Also looks like there is an info.plist with some startup info in it...